# What is the equivalent statement of this VHDL assignment?

Tags: vhdl

The VHDL code is:

```
next_x(7 downto 0) <= rec_data;
```

What does this line do? What is the equivalent statement?  This line is within a process and is executed when condition_1 is true.

My guess is that this statement will update next_x?

Can someone please explain the statement and find the equivalent, if any?

Thanks.

Comment: The equivalent statement in what?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a **signal assignment**, it *schedules* `next_x` to have the value of `rec_data` after the process completes.  The biggest caveat to be aware of is that a subsequent read of signal `next_x` in the process where this change is scheduled will return the old value of this signal -- the change has not taken effect yet.  You can think of it as being executed concurrently with all other signal assignments in the process, but multiple assignments of the same signal are allowed and only the last will take effect.

On the other hand, **variable assignments** take effect immediately, so changes are visible by all subsequent statements in the process, much like imperative programming languages.

The equivalent **variable** assignment would be `next_x(7 downto 0) := rec_data;`, but `next_x` must then be a variable, not a signal.

Here is a good summary of [signal versus variable assignment](http://www.gmvhdl.com/signals.htm).

Comment: I don't think the question mentioned variables.

Comment: It was a guess.  I parsed the title as: what is the equivalent "statement" of this VHDL "assignment"?  From that I assumed the OP was referring to the provided signal assignment as an "assignment" and was looking for a related concept they called a "statement".  The closest thing I can think of are variable assignments.  I didn't read much more into the question than that, so hopefully they'll expand if this is a severely misguided answer.  Learning the metalanguage to describe another language is half the challenge sometimes.